# PHP print files in directory to printer

Tags: php

I'm trying to print files directly from html button called print and this is my code:

```
if($handle = printer_open("\\\\servername\\printername")){
    printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw");
    $output = "file.pdf";
    printer_write($handle,$output);
    printer_close($handle);
}
```

But, the code doesn't work, did I miss something?

If I put `echo "test"` inside the if statement, it echoed, and it means that my printer path is correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

The function printer_open is not a native PHP call.  It exists in specific packages available online, but does not work without recompiling PHP with the package installed.  A useful script others, including myself, have used in the past is to hand it directly to the system call.

```
system("lp $filename");
```

There are many options that you can add in the system call; one option needed would be destination printer.  You can check the man page for lp for details.